# Haskell how to add a float to all members of an integer list

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell, but I'm trying to add a float to all members of an integer list in Haskell and I'm having trouble getting past the errors and such.

Basically

```
addAll xs = map (+3.5) xs
```

Where xs is an integer list.

Comment: The code that you've given does compile (although it doesn't have the type that the prose implies), so it would be helpful if you could post the full code and the error.

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to convert each `Integer` to a `Float` before you can add a `Float` to it.

You can use [`fromInteger`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromInteger) for this. Its type is

```
Num a => Integer -> a
```

which, for our purpose here, specializes to

```
Integer -> Float
```

So here's what the `addAll` function looks like:

```
addAll :: [Integer] -> [Float]
addAll xs = map (\x -> fromInteger x + 3.5) xs
```

Example usage in GHCi:

```
λ> addAll [1, 2, 3]
[4.5,5.5,6.5]
```

Answer (score 5):

### What would you expect the result list to be?

It can be `[Float]` or `[Integer]` - in Haskell you should be explicit about that.

### 1. `[Integer]`

You need either to [`round`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:round) the floating point number before you multiply:

```
map (+ (round (3.5 :: Float))) [1..(10 :: Integer)]
```

### 2. `[Float]`

Or convert the integers with [`fromInteger`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromInteger)

```
[3.5 + fromInteger x | x <- xs]
map ((+3.5) . fromInteger) xs
```

as adding numbers only works if both summands are of the same type, you can see this in the type signature

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

all `a`s have to be the same and be an instance of the `Num`-typeclass (much alike an interface in Java, if you have experience with that).

Note: There is no automatic conversion in Haskell<sup>1</sup>.

<sub><sup>1</sup>: Except for numeric literals like `0,1,2…` they are converted using `fromInteger`, numeric literals like `1.1`,`2.2` etc. are converted by [`fromRational`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromRational) and `String` literals when you enable `OverloadedStrings` with `fromString`.</sub>